# MongoDb - Get logs of the executed queries

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using mongodb C# driver to perform all the operations on mongodb. 
I want the logs like time taken to execute the operation, locks acquired, COLLSCAN/IXSCAN stage etc..

All I am getting now in my logs is the statements for creation and dropping of collections and indexes.

```
2019-08-26T14:44:57.444+0530 I INDEX    [conn2] build index on: TestDb.System2 properties: { v: 2, unique: true, key: { description: 1 }, name: "description_1", ns: "TestDb.System2", background: true, sparse: false }
2019-08-26T14:44:57.444+0530 I INDEX    [conn2] build index done.  scanned 0 total records. 0 secs
2019-08-26T14:44:57.642+0530 I COMMAND  [conn2] dropDatabase TestDb starting
2019-08-26T14:44:57.642+0530 I COMMAND  [conn2] dropDatabase TestDb finished
```

How can I get the logs for the queries I am performing.

Also, I am aware of `system.profile` collection. I do not want to push the logs to this collection by enabling the profiling.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the logs of all the writes

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: testDb
> use myTestDb
switched to db myTestDb
> db.getProfilingLevel()
0
> db.setProfilingLevel(2)
{ "was" : 0, "slowms" : 1, "ok" : 1 }
> db.getProfilingLevel()
2
> db.system.profile.find().pretty()
```

Reference : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

This Query Logs all Operation